# Notice: Undefined offset: 27 Why these error generated in PHP?

Tags: php

I used below code but that gives me an Error like "Notice : Undefined offset: 27" . Why these error generated or what these error means ? please any one help me.

```
//Code ... final_display2 is found some array.

for($p=0; $p<sizeof($final_display2); $p=$p+2){
    $b = $p+1;
    $len1 = strlen($final_display2[$p])+strlen($final_display2[$b]); //these line gives error 116
    if($len1 < 3200){
        array_push($final_display,$final_display2[$p].$final_display2[$b]);  //and these one also 118       }else{
        array_push($final_display,$final_display2[$p]);
        array_push($final_display,$final_display2[$b]);
    }
}
```

### ERROR!!

[image]

Comment: It looks like `sizeof($final_display2)==27`, so when `$p==sizeof($final_display2)-1` ie. `26`, then `$b == 27`, and since `$final_display2` is `0` based, `$final_display2[$b]`or`$final_display2[27]` does not exist. You need to check `if(isset($final_display2[$b]))` before proceeding.

Comment: @Sean It's work can you please add in answer so i accept it

Comment: @GunjanPatel tried to write your loop cleaner! Hope it works¨

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error occurs when `$p==sizeof($final_display2)-1`, so `$b==sizeof($final_display2)`, which will result in a `Undefined Offset`.

ie. if `sizeof($final_display2)==27`, when `$p==26`, then `$b==27` and `$final_display2[$b]`/`$final_display2[27]` does not exist.

Try using `if(isset($final_display2[$b]))` ->

```
for($p=0; $p<sizeof($final_display2); $p=$p+2){
    $b = $p+1;

    if(isset($final_display2[$b])){ //only run if $final_display2[$b] exists

    $len1 = strlen($final_display2[$p])+strlen($final_display2[$b]); //these line gives error 116
    if($len1 < 3200){
        array_push($final_display,$final_display2[$p].$final_display2[$b]);  //and these one also 118       }else{
        array_push($final_display,$final_display2[$p]);
        array_push($final_display,$final_display2[$b]);
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `$p` instead of `$b` since your looping trough all items in `$final_display2`, but your adding 1 to `$b` it's an offset! (Also change in your `for` loop this `$p=$p+2` to `$p++`)

Little example:

You have 5 items in `$final_display2` so the loop is like this:

```
for($p=0; $p<5; $p++)
    //So if your at the last element ($p = 4) but your adding 1 to $b and use it you have a offset
```

Edit:

I think your looking for something like this:

```
    foreach($final_display2 as $k => $v) {

        if( isset($final_display2[$k+1]) ) {
            if($k == 0 || $k % 2 == 0) {
                $len1 = strlen($final_display2[$k])+strlen($final_display2[$k+1]);

                if($len1 < 3200){
                    array_push($final_display,$final_display2[$k].$final_display2[$k+1]); 
                    array_push($final_display,$final_display2[$k]);
                    array_push($final_display,$final_display2[$k+1]);
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I make a logic like that loop take only even number of array element and make summation of array[0] and array[1] finding length.

Comment: @GunjanPatel Sry i think i don't get that! You want to go trough only even numbers? And then what you want to add together?